# Jquery isn't working outside the contact form 7

Tags: jquery

I've added some js code into contact form 7 for autocompletion field and it works fine. But when I move the code to another js file, it doesn't work anymore. Another js files are working fine.

I'm using the awesomeplete code for autocompletion field from GitHub. https://github.com/LeaVerou/awesomplete

Here is the code:

```
var input = document.getElementById("list_1");
var awesomplete = new Awesomplete(input, {
list: ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"],
    minChars: 1
});
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not accurate enough, please elaborate. And show how you include your JS file. Any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work anymore"? Any error messages?

Comment: I said doesn't work, cause I can find the js file in the page source. That means it linked perfectly. Also, I've checked the console. No error. Just not working.

Comment: @SabbirAhmed please post the markup for your view as well

Comment: <script>
    var input = document.getElementById("airport");
    new Awesomplete(input, {list: ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]});
  </script>

Comment: I've just added this script inside the contact form 7. But when I tried to move the script into a js file outside the contact form 7. It stop working. Like, I moved the code in example.js file and linked it to the theme and run, nothing work.

Comment: I can't understand, why people can't understand my problem.

Comment: Finally, I got my solution. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the script is getting the input field id from inside the contact form 7. So, when I tried to get the id from outside the contact form 7, the script stops working. Cause, the script doesn't find any id outside the contact form 7.

I've just linked a js file to my theme. And used the path (http://localhost/experiment/wp-content/themes/Web_Design/script.js?ver=4.9.9'>) inside the contact form 7. Then it works perfectly. That means the script exists inside the contact form 7 but also exists outside the contact form 7. Make sense, right?

Hope it's useful to you.